# How to select specific number in a string based on the stated position in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this string '275,278,222'

How to SELECT only 278, which is in the second position? or SELECT only 222 which is in the third position?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with MySQL. Perhaps see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

second position : `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(STAFFID_, ',', 2),',',-1)`

third position : `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(STAFFID_, ',', 3),',',-1)`